# TrackBarEdit values

Tags: wpf, devexpress

Can't get how to show signs under values of Devexpress TrackBarEdit. For example there must be date selection of 10 values... I need to make 10 signatures of dates under TrackBarEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the current version of [DevExpress TrackBarEdit](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7915) doesn't support this functionality.
I've found a suggestion in [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) about this: [Labels for ticks in a TrackBarEdit](http://www.devexpress.dev/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q406457).

Comment: Very strange, because in Demo Center there is a label for ticks... so unfair